# Windows batch start up script to move windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup

I'm experienced with many different programming languages. I decided to expand my horizons and try some simple batch scripts. I have a windows start up script that I'm running.

startupScript.bat

```
start "" "explorer.exe"
start "" "explorer.exe"
start "" "taskmgr.exe"
start "" "cmd.exe"
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Works great. I would like to be able to move the windows where I want them though. I'm running 5 monitors, and I want the two explorer windows on my bottom left monitor each taking half the screen. I want the command prompt and task manager in my top left monitor each taking half of the screen, and I want my chrome browser on my bottom right monitor taking up the whole screen.

Chrome remembers where it was, so that isn't a problem. The other windows don't though.

Is there a way for me to run keystrokes after each program is started? I could do "winkey+left", "winkey+left", etc... for each window if that's possible. Otherwise how might I accomplish this?

Also, when the command line is run, the properties go to defaults. Is there a way to use my command line settings so that it is sized right, has quick edit mode enabled, and has the colors that I set it to?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try setting up a shortcut to the application with shortcut/Run=normal window; layout and hues to taste. Then start the shortcut (.lnk file) in your batch. Certainly works for `cmd` - can't say for the others...

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). I don't remember enough to tell you what your script should look like, but the little I remember tells me all you need is in their toolbox.